# Is there a convenient way to initialize a list of strings in Scala?

Tags: scala

In Perl I can do

```
my @l = qw( str1 str2 str3 str4 )
```

And in Ruby

```
l = %w{ str1 str2 str3 str4 }
```

But in Scala it looks like I'm stuck with

```
val l = List( "str1", "str2", "str3", "str4" )
```

Do I really need all those `"`s and `,`s?

Comment: So how do Perl and Ruby deal with whitespace in `str1` for example?

Comment: 0__ in perl, "qw" means quote word and splits on white space.  For strings with spaces qw is not appropriate, the initialisation would in that case be just like scala

Comment: Yes, what @Vorsprung said. It doesn't cover all cases, but an useful subset.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could do

```
implicit class StringList(val sc: StringContext) extends AnyVal {
  def qw(): List[String] = 
    sc.parts.flatMap(_.split(' '))(collection.breakOut)
}

qw"str1 str2 str3"
```

Or via implicit class:

```
implicit class StringList(val s: String) extends AnyVal {
  def qw: List[String] = s.split(' ').toList
}

"str1 str2 str3".qw
```

(Both require Scala 2.10, although the second one can be adapted for Scala 2.9)

Comment: Clever use of the new string interpolation factility. It (the first one) is Scala 2.10 only, though.

Comment: Actually, I'd split the parts, but interpolate args in their original places, without splitting them.

Comment: You must not put arguments to the method. `def qw() = ...` is enough.

Comment: @sschaef - ah, didn't know. i have edited the answer accordingly